# Why is the complexity class of this Fibonacci Sequence O(2^n)?

Tags: class, complexity-theory, fibonacci

```
void allFib(int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
  }
}

int fib(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) return 0;
  else if (n == 1) return 1;
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

This is from CTCI. I originally thought it would be O(n * 2^n), but as the book pointed out this is a common mistake. It ends up being O(2^n) but I don't understand their wording. Also, for an input of 1 into fib(1), why would there be 2^1 steps? Wouldn't it just be 1 step, because n == 1 so you are just returning 1?

Comment: Post your code in question itself. Don't post a screenshot of your code

Comment: Do you mean the complexity of `allFib` or `fib`? I can see how the former could easily be mistaken for `O(n * 2^n)`, but not the latter.

Comment: The complexity for allFib. I thought it would be O(n * 2^n)

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity refers to the **asymptotic** behavior of an algorithm. That is, when `n -> infinity` or when `n` is extremely large. At `n = 1`, yes the algorithm would just be 1 step, but that doesn't suggest anything about the time complexity. In your code, you can see that each `fib()` call will make two more `fib()` calls, so if you supply `n`, you can image the algorithm running 2 * 2 * 2 * ... `n` times. Hence, the time complexity O(2^n).

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When discussing big O notation in algorithm complexity, it is not an accurate function of the number of steps for each and every input size.

Freely defined, it marks to which "order of magnitude" this complexity belongs.

Formal definition includes a certain "starting value", that for all larger 
inputs the complexity "behaves" as n^2 (in our case).

So, your example of n=1 does not contradict the fact that it is O(n^2). Just consider the starting value to be 2.
You can easily see that in each step the algorithm performs twice as much computations as the previous did. So asymptotically, it increases as n^2 increases.

Answer (score 0):

The book first assumes an *upper-bound* for the complexity of `fib` to be `O(2^n)`. To see how this is derived, let's modify the function `fib` slightly:

```
int gib(int n) {
   if (n <= 0) return 0;
   else if (n == 1) return 1;
   return gib(n - 1) + gib(n - 1);
}
```

Note that the argument to the second recursive call is now `n - 1` instead of `n - 2`. This gives an upper bound as a larger argument will of course mean more computation time. The time complexity function can be expressed as a simple recurrence relation:

[image]

Thus `fib` is *also* bounded by `O(2^n)`. (In fact, because of the second argument being `n - 2`, the actual tight bound is `~ Θ(1.58^n)`; you can obtain this by substituting `a^n` instead of `2^n` and solving)

---

Now let's see about `allFib`. The time complexity is the summation of `fib`:

[image]

Note that this is *exactly* what we had before! - a *geometric series*. Hence the result is the same as the last line for the complexity for `gib`, i.e. `O(2^n)`.